# AWS S3 Bucket Policy - Read only access for specific "folder"

Tags: security, amazon-s3

I am trying to limit access for one of the IAM users to a "folder" within an S3 bucket. I thought I had this configured correctly, but the read access does not appear to be working.

```
{
        "Sid": "TEST_PublicReadGetObject",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::807676775814:user/project/api/testuserapi-abc123"
        },
          "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:ListBucketByTags",
            "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
            "s3:ListBucketVersions",
            "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
        ],
        "Resource":
            "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket-securitytest/timeline/*"
    }
```

Is there something I am missing? Is there sometimes a delay in making these changes or should it be instant?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out I had to allow ListBucket access first and then add the Action to allow only GetObject for that "folder". :) --- Just need to read the documentation a little more thoroughly

```
{
        "Sid": "TEST_ListItems",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::807676775814:user/project/api/testuserapi"
        },
        "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "TEST_PublicReadGetObject",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::807676775814:user/project/api/testuserapi
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket/Timeline/*"
    }`
```

Comment: If desired, you could probably limit `ListBucket` to only work for a given `Prefix`, so they can only list the contents of that folder.